# Display user input on page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having this trouble for a while and I can't quite figure it out. I want to display user input as an h1 element. How do I do this?

```js
let allAssignments;

if (localStorage.getItem("everyAssignment")) {
  allAssignments = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("everyAssignment"))
} else {
  allAssignments = []
}

function submitFunc() {
  let names = document.getElementById("name").value;
  allAssignments.push(names)
  localStorage.setItem("everyAssignment", JSON.stringify(allAssignments));
  let finalArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("everyAssignment"));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="submitFunc()">Submit</button>
<input placeholder="Enter Name Here" id="name">
```

I want to create a div element for each item in the local storage, and use .innerHTML to insert an h1 element with the name of **each** value in the array. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```js
const submitFunc = () => {
  const value = document.getElementById('name').value;
  const parent = document.createElement('div');
  const pTag = document.createElement('p');
  pTag.innerText = value;
  parent.appendChild(pTag);
  document.body.appendChild(parent);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="submitFunc()">Submit</button>
<input placeholder="Enter Name Here" id="name">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it as a H1 element you can do the following

```
    const submitFunc = () => {
      const value = document.getElementById('name').value;
      const parent = document.createElement('div');
      const hTag = document.createElement('h1');
      var node = document.createTextNode(value);
      hTag.appendChild(node);

      parent.appendChild(pTag);
      document.body.appendChild(parent);
    }
```

This is the markup to be used.

```
<button onclick="submitFunc()">Submit</button>
<input placeholder="Enter Name Here" id="name">
```